# How to get the prompt message while redirecting the file?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have a file test which is already present in the directory, when I use

```
  `cat > test` or `ls > test`
```

The content in the file will be truncated and the data will be lost, So I want a prompt message before redirecting the file. Your help would be most useful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI: `set -C` (noclobber) will prevent you from overwriting files like this. You can overwrite this with `>|` ... Re: Question, just use `if [ -f myfile ]` with `read` to get the answer...

Comment: I created a more complete example as an Answer...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker - Yes its working, is there any other way?  And what is use of `set -C`??

Comment: Another way to do what? There are usually many ways to do most tasks. You don't *need* `set -C`; it's just a good habit, IMHO.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Yes I need that, but I just want to know is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Probably, yes, but this is the obvious way to do it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example might be this:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Prevent > from overwriting files, use >| to overwrite files anyway
# It's good for safety to always enable this...
set -C

file=xxx

# Test if file exist with -f
if [ -f "$file" ]; then
    echo "Overwrite $file? [Y/n]"

    # Read user input
    read answer

    # Is the answer "n" or "N", we exit
    # The default is to continue on any other input (you could change this, of course)
    case "$answer" in
        [nN]) exit 2 ;;
    esac
fi

# Overwrite the file, we use >| because we set noclobber
echo 'New' >| "$file"
```